# Passing data from layout to block controller using setData

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to set a variable in my local.xml file for my custom block:

```
<layout>
    <!-- ... -->
    <page_homepage>
        <!-- ... -->
        <reference name="root">    
            <!-- ... -->
            <block type="core/template" name="home_page_sections" template="page/homepage/sections.phtml">
                <block type="layout/carousel" name="featured_carousel">
                    <action method="setData">
                        <name>filter_attribute</name>
                        <value>is_featured_product</value>
                    </action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </page_homepage>
</layout>
```

But I am not getting the data on the other end in my controller:

```
class Foo_Layout_Block_Carousel extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $filterAttribute = $this->getFilterAttribute(); // Nothing
        $filterAttribute = $this->getData('filter_attribute'); // Nada

        // Alright, fine, what DO I have?!
        var_dump($this->getData()); // array(0) {} ... Argh!
    }
}
```

From all my searching I've found that this really should work, but since it does not, I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious. Here is my layout module's configuration (I'm using a single module to define a homepage and any other blocks I need for the site):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Foo_Layout>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Foo_Layout>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <page>
            <layouts>
                <foo_homepage translate="label">
                    <label>Homepage</label>
                    <template>page/homepage.phtml</template>
                    <layout_handle>page_homepage</layout_handle>
                </foo_homepage>
            </layouts>
        </page>
        <blocks>
            <layout>
                <class>Foo_Layout_Block</class>
            </layout>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When the layout rendering code encounters this

```
<block type="layout/carousel" name="featured_carousel">
```

It **immediately** instantiates the block. That means the block's  `__construct` method is called **before** your `setData` method is called.  So, at the time of construction, no data has been set, which is why your calls to `var_dump` return an empty array.

Also, immediately after being created, the block is added to the layout

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php
...
$block->setLayout($this);
...
```

When this happens, the block's `_prepareLayout` method is called.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
public function setLayout(Mage_Core_Model_Layout $layout)
{
    $this->_layout = $layout;
    Mage::dispatchEvent('core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before', array('block' => $this));
    $this->_prepareLayout();
    Mage::dispatchEvent('core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after', array('block' => $this));
    return $this;
}
```

So, this means that any data set in your layout update xml is **still** not available, even in `_prepareLayout`.  Once the system is done creating the block, it moves on to the next XML node.

```
<action method="setData">
    <name>filter_attribute</name>
    <value>is_featured_product</value>
</action>
```

and calls the `setData` method.  Now your block has its data set.

Try defining a `_beforeToHtml` method on your block and checking for data there.   (Assuming your block is being rendered)

Comment: Wow, fantastic answer. Defining a `_beforeToHtml` did the trick and will work for my use case perfectly.

Comment: Alan, since posting this answer have you found any other Mage_Core_Block_Abstract or Mage_Core_Block_Template method that may be useful in overriding, if we want to utilize data set by `<action method="setData">` XML layout instructions? I'd like to set some cache settings on the block based off the data I set however there doesn't seem to be any good methods to override for this. the `final public toHtml()` method will attempt to load from cache before the `_beforeToHtml()` method, and therefore won't work for the purpose I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

i think that the definition of the block is wrong. Can you try

```
<block type="layout/carousel"name="featured_carousel" attribute=value>
```

and in the phtml retrieve the value with $this->getAttribute()

You can see the next example:

```
class Elblogdeselo_Blocksparams_Block_Test extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract{    
protected function _toHtml(){

    //$nombre=$this->getNombre();
    $nombre=$this->getData('nombre');
    $html=$html." ".$this->getData('nuevo_parametro');
    return $html;
}
```

}

And in the definition in the backend i put in my home CMS

```
{{block type="blocksparams/test" name="bloque_con_parametros" nuevo_parametro="nuevo" nombre="david"  template="blocksparams/test.phtml"}}
```

another example that i find in a extension:

```
protected function _construct(){
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setData('customer', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer());
    $this->addData(Mage::getModel('model/model'));     
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I'm still not getting any data. I tried `<block type="layout/carousel" filter_attribute="is_featured_product" ... />` and in my controller, I used both `$this->getFilterAttribute()` and `$this->getData('filter_attribute')`.

Comment: Yes, it is there in the template .phtml. I guess I misunderstood what would happen when you `setData` in the layout. Is there any way to pass data from the layout xml to the block controller?

Comment: the sample that i add in my question work fine for me. I made many time add parameter sinde the _construct, for example add a model to retrieve in the template.

Comment: Good to know, but I've got to stay away from the CMS (its content is displayed after these carousel blocks). I think I'll just create a new block controller for each of my filter types.

Comment: @davidselo -- I'm not 100% certain, but I'm pretty sure the reason the OP was having trouble with the attributes is he overrode the PHP controller, and called the parent controller without any arguments.   Key/Value data set in the attributes like that should be available in both the internal constructor (_construct) and the _prepareLayout method. These paramaters are passed to the block's __construct at the time of instantiation, and then set as data properties using func_get_args. With an empty call to parent::__construct(), that default behavior is overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Pass variables from a layout to a block:

```
<action method="setData">
   <name>variablename</name>
   <value>10</value>
</action>
```

Get value of variable in block from layout:

```
$variableName = $this->getVariablename();
$variableName = $this->getData('variablename');
```